I’m seeing cloudy whitish spots after using water-based polycrylic. How to remove?
I applied polycrylic over a dark walnut penetrating stain and allowed the stain to dry for several days.  After applying my first coat of poly, I let it dry overnight and then sanded (#320) removed dust, now that there are cloudy, whitish spots in some areas.  I’m afraid if I put a second coat of poly on I’ll seal in the white spots.  Is the re a way to remove these, and what is causing this?  I’ve refinished quite a few pieces using poly and never experienced this.  Ambient temperature is 72° and humidity between 60 and 70%.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. We need pictures I think to get a better idea of what this might be. For starters the entire thing should really be clouded to a degree from the scratches that sanding/other abrasion introduce to the surface, so presumably the spots are much whiter. Also, which sheen version is this? Had a late thought that this might possibly be clumps of the matting agent if you're using any of the reduced-sheen versions (the matting agent is an ultra fine powder which settles to the bottom as a whitish layer, and very thorough mixing can be required to redistribute it evenly).

How do I add pictures?  I tried copying & pasting but it didn’t work.

@DeniseDoherty see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Select "Edit" to make changes to your post and then select the image icon (mountains).  A box should appear in which you can drop your image

The cloudy spots are likely caused by moisture trapped in the polycrylic, which can happen with water-based finishes, especially in humid conditions. To fix it, try lightly sanding the affected areas with fine-grit sandpaper (#320 or higher) and wiping the surface clean. You can then apply a thin coat of polycrylic to those areas to see if it clears up. If the spots are deeper, you might need to sand down a bit more and reapply the finish. Lowering humidity or using a dehumidifier while applying the finish can help prevent this in the future.
